# Wordpress - display a taxonomy by label

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, taxonomy

Is there a way i can display post with a taxonomy label?
I got this:

```
$args = array(
'posts_per_page' => 2,
'post_type' =>"works", 
'post_status' => array('publish')
```

and i want to to something like that to display some post with the label "*gamed*"

```
$args = array(
'posts_per_page' => 2,
'post_type' =>"works", 
    'tax_query' => array(
      array(
      "singular_label" => 'gamed',

  )
    'post_status' => array('publish')
```

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: http://bit.ly/VjVNkC - take a look here.

Comment: Yeah thanks man, i've already done that, but i cannot find a way to display it using a specific label

Comment: The taxonomy query doesn't have `singular_label` key. See the `tax_query` syntax [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters). You can only query for terms by their slug or id.